# Restoring parent from the desktop window

Tags: c#, .net, window, desktop, handle

I've imported:

```
public static extern IntPtr SetParent(
        IntPtr hWndChild,      // handle to window
        IntPtr hWndNewParent   // new parent window
    );
```

from `user32.dll` in my windows forms application and continuously setting `SetParent(hwndf,hwndParent);` (if a variable is true) in a background thread.

Where

```
IntPtr hwndf = Control.Handle;
IntPtr hwndParent = FindWindow("ProgMan", null);
```

My question **How do i reset the parent handle to be the default windows form handle, aka, how do I not display the window on top of the desktop window anymore?** and is following, Is this an efficient way of doing this (repeatedly?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind. I could just use

```
SetParent(hwndf, new IntPtr(0));
```

When I wanted to "reset" the form window parent. The only problem was the the window was minimized, so my solution was running `ShowWindow(hwndf, SW_RESTORE);` after importing these methods from `user32.dll`!

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr ShowWindow(
        IntPtr hWnd,      // handle to window
        uint nCmdShow
    );
    private const uint SW_RESTORE = 0x09;
```